# Transformación XSLT: Pasar parametros xslt y después leerlos

Tags: java, xslt

Tengo un problema con la lectura de un parámetro, ya que creo que no lo esta leyendo al momento de realizar la validación.

```
TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer transformer = factory.newTransformer(xslt);
        transformer.setParameter("pruebaTest", responseType);

 //responseType: es una variable que guarda el nombre de un flujo que quiero identificar, este puede variar.
```

En mi transformación realizo esto:

```
 <xsl:param name="pruebaTest"></xsl:param>
<xsl:when test="$pruebaTest= 'algo'">

//tareas a ejecutar si resulta que  $pruebaTest= 'algo'"
```

El problema como menciono, no me esta tomando en cuenta la validación, creó que no transmuta el valor que recibe como parámetro. No me marca ningún error, simplemente no lo hace.

¿Alguien sabe del tema? ¿Pueden ayudarme?

De antemano gracias!